# Grails HQL QuerySyntaxException

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql, grails-2.0

I have the following HQL query. When I run it I'm getting the exception:

> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: on

My code is as follows. Anyone know how to fix this so it works?

```
def results = LineItem.executeQuery("\
        select \
            li_ch.eventId as event_id, \
            sum(CASE li_ch.lineItemType WHEN :product THEN 1 WHEN :refund THEN (CASE li_p.lineItemType WHEN :product THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) ELSE 0 END) as sold, \
            sum(li_ch.amount) as gross \
        from \
            LineItem li_ch LEFT JOIN LineItem li_p on li_ch.parentLineItem.id = li_p.id, \
            Sale s \
        where \
            s.id = li_ch.sale.id AND \
            li_ch.eventId in (238141) AND \
            s.saleStatusType in (:paid, :refunded, :partialRefunded) AND \
            li_ch.lineItemType in (:product, :refund)  \
        group by li_ch.eventId", [product: LineItemType.PRODUCT, refund: LineItemType.REFUND, paid: SaleStatusType.PAID, refunded: SaleStatusType.REFUNDED, partialRefunded: SaleStatusType.PARTIAL_REFUND])
```

This gives the following exception:

```
[2014-08-21 09:34:52,666] hql.PARSER line 1:371: unexpected token: on
[2014-08-21 09:34:52,685] errors.GrailsExceptionResolver QuerySyntaxException occurrwhen processing request: [GET] /inventory/events/salesData - parameters:
eventIds: 238141
unexpected token: on near line 1, column 371 [            select                 li_ch.eventId as event_id,                 sum(CASE li_ch.lineItemType WHEN :product THEN 1 WHEN :refund THEN (CASE li_p.lineItemType WHEN :product THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) ELSE 0 END) as sold,                 sum(li_ch.amount) as gross             from                 com.acme.inventory.domain.LineItem li_ch LEFT JOIN LineItem li_p on li_ch.parentLineItem.id = li_p.id,                 com.acme.inventory.domain.Sale s             where                 s.id = li_ch.sale.id AND                 li_ch.eventId in (238141) AND                 s.saleStatusType in (:paid, :refunded, :partialRefunded) AND                 li_ch.lineItemType in (:product, :refund)              group by li_ch.eventId]. Stacktrace follows:
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: on near line 1, column 371 [            select                 li_ch.eventId as event_id,                 sum(CASE li_ch.lineItemType WHEN :product THEN 1 WHEN :refund THEN (CASE li_p.lineItemType WHEN :product THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) ELSE 0 END) as sold,                 sum(li_ch.amount) as gross             from                 com.acme.inventory.domain.LineItem li_ch LEFT JOIN LineItem li_p on li_ch.parentLineItem.id = li_p.id,                 com.acme.inventory.domain.Sale s             where                 s.id = li_ch.sale.id AND                 li_ch.eventId in (238141) AND                 s.saleStatusType in (:paid, :refunded, :partialRefunded) AND                 li_ch.lineItemType in (:product, :refund)              group by li_ch.eventId]
at com.acme.inventory.services.SaleRestService$$EOnaEzWy.eventSaleData(SaleRestService.groovy:15)
at com.acme.inventory.controllers.SaleRestController.eventSaleData(SaleRestController.groovy:13)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Comment: The unexpected token `ON` exactly as I said, Correct? The problem is the keyword **ON**

Answer (score 0):

The full exception could help but I gues that related to :

- [14.3. Associations and joins](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins)

We are not allowed to use **`ON`** keyword wit a JOIN statement. This is driven by the mapping.

What we can do, is to extend the generated ON `(generated by Hibernate based on mapping)` - but for that we have a keyword **`WITH`**. So this should help:

Instead of:

```
// wrong
from
  LineItem li_ch LEFT JOIN LineItem li_p on li_ch.parentLineItem.id = li_p.id, 

// extend the JOIN condition using WITH
from
  LineItem li_ch LEFT JOIN LineItem li_p with li_ch.parentLineItem.id = li_p.id,
```

Comment: I tried switching the 'on' to a 'with' but I get a new exception: `org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join!`

Comment: Exactly.. because now we do have other issue. but the ON was preventing us from seeing this error. Please, correctly observe this link http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins to see how the FROM and JOIN can look like...

Comment: Thanks for the link but it looks like I'm doing the join similar to how it's being used in the example: `from Cat as cat
    left join cat.kittens as kitten
        with kitten.bodyWeight > 10.0`. Do you see any difference between the example code and my code?

Comment: The issue is here: `LineItem li_ch LEFT JOIN LineItem li_p`, it should be containing the path, in which is the LineItem, related to the LineItem. e.g. if it is parent child it should be like: `LineItem as li_ch LEFT JOIN li_ch.LineItem as li_p`. see the second part is **`li_ch.LineItem`**. As I expressed in my Answer: The ON clause is defined by mapping *(It could be only extend with the WITH)* But that mean, that we should show the relation coming from mapping. Does it help?

Comment: I see what you're getting at and I appreciate your help. `li_ch.LineItem` isn't valid syntax though.

Comment: I know ;) it must be the name of the property mapped.. like li_ch.Parent or li_Ch.Manager... Because what you do is: join two same entities. And that could be done only, if these two do have some relation ... Or it could be the Cartesian product, but only like this: `LineItem as li_ch, LineItem as li_p, Sale s` ... Does this help? it is really not any magic. just Hibernate is not about SQL but about querying on top of ORM